# Weird effect when implementing sonar animation

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to implement a sonar effect on some icons on my site. I am trying to get it to look like these icons that sonar  http://www.webmeh.com/#process

mine look like here jaychiasson.astuteimage.com

I just cant quite figure out my icons fade out all the way and dont just have the ring that goes outward from the border of the icon. Any insight?

Comment: I am also stuck trying to make the <span>'s beneath the icons move down to properly space them

Comment: ok figured out the problem with the spans. I realized that <a> tags are inline attributes and cant take top or bottom margins so i put them in <p> tags and put a margin bottom on them. All better. The sonar animation issue is still bugging me a lot though.